# Necessity of Defining Enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

One derivation of enthalpy by Kittel and Kroemer uses: $dW’ = dW + d(PV) = dU + d(PV) - dQ = dH - dQ$. My understanding is, however, that $dW$ already includes $d(PV)$, so I find it redundant to add $d(PV)$ to the work. If $d(PV)$ and $dW$ are separate, then what kind of work does $dW$ denote (most work done by gases in thermodynamics is expansion and compression from my experience)? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point of defining [different thermodynamic potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential) is to be able to choose which of the parameters are *independent variables* and which are *response variables*. Switching between different pairs of conjugated parameters - $(P,V)$, $(T,S)$, and $(\mu, N)$ - is achieved by using the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation). It is the very same Legendre transformation that is used to convert from Lagrangian to Hamiltonian description in the classical mechanics, except that in thermodynamics it is defined with a different sign.

Specifically, enthalpy is particularly useful, e.g., for describing thermodynamics of macromolecules molecules in chemistry, where controlling pressure is more natural than assuming constant volume.

Answer (score 0):

Enthalpy is just a very convenient parameter to work with when analyzing many kinds of thermodynamics problems, rather than always writing U+PV.  When you have more experience, you will see how often it comes into play.  For example, for constant pressure expansion of compression of a gas, it is equal to the amount of heat you have to add or remove, respectively.  But this is just the tip of the iceberg.